Are there any current scholars defending the "new" mathematics movement in the US or elsewhere?
I'm researching the new mathematics movement that took place from the 1950's to the 1970's in the US.
I've run across many criticisms of the movement, obviously.  There are the criticisms by Richard Feynman and Morris Kline (author of "Why Johnny Can't Add:  The failure of New Math").  Also, there's Time magazine's placement of the movement as one of the top 100 worst ideas of the 20th century, along with many more criticisms that aren't as famous as these three.
Are there any scholars that still defend the new mathematics movement currently?  That's my question.

I don't have an answer to your specific question, but the criticisms you mention running across suggest that you haven't dug very deeply into this area yet. I recommend looking at the references in my answer to Where can I find primary sources from the New Math movement in the 60s?, along with my comment to this answer. Also, the other answers and comments where my just cited comments appear could be useful.

To add to the suggestion by David Renfro, I suggest looking at by book The New Math: A Political History. Christopher J. Phillips (2014), University of Chicago Press. There is a good review of this book by James Fey in the Journal for Research in Mathematics Education. The review is available on JSTOR.

It is also worth pointing out that while the curriculum innovations of the New Math (e.g.: the notation and language of set theory, numerals in bases other than 10, etc.) have almost entirely fallen out of the K-12 curriculum, they remain present within the curriculum of teacher education courses. See any textbook book with a phrase like "Math for teachers" in its title for examples.
